# Allowing web broswer to execute script

Tags: command-line

I have a script named script.sh which contains tshark script to filter all column I want and convert it to csv and I run it through web broswer
The problem is that I get nothing on the file ouptut, I get a file but there's nothing in it.
How to handle that

In my codeigniter project, I have three folders: file_pcap, files_csv and Dossier_script
The user upload the pcap file to the file_pcap, and my script convert it into csv and move it to the files_csv

There is the script:

```
DOSSIER_A_TRAITER=/opt/lampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter
echo $i
for files in $DOSSIER_A_TRAITER/file_pcap/*.pcap
do

    chmod -R 777 ${files}
    tshark -r ${files} -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e _ws.col.Protocol -E separator=, -E occurrence=f >$files.csv
    echo $files.csv
    echo $DOSSIER_A_TRAITER/files_csv/
    #mv  $DOSSIER_A_TRAITER/file_pcap/*.csv $DOSSIER_A_TRAITER/files_csv
    #rm -f $files

done
```

I want to run this script on my codeigniter project, the function who call this in controller is like this:

```
public function execute()

{
  shell_exec('sh path/to/the/script/script.sh');
}
```

And the group who should use this script is "daemon" as the command line ls -l shows

Comment: @NickAndoniaina we can't help you debug a script you don't show us. Please [edit] your question and show us what script you are running, tell us what user is running it, how it is being in the browser etc. The more details you give us, the better your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: what permission do you have on ```$DOSSIER_A_TRAITER/file_pcap/```

Comment: drwxrwxrwx  on root

Comment: @NickAndoniaina please [edit] your question and tell us i) what user is running the script? ii) does that user have access to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter`?